# Develop an application for blackberry 10 and play book in webworks which sdk i should download?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

Actually from WebWorks I want to make a BlackBerry app with which I target both the BlackBerry 10 and Playbook devices. So for this, which SDK I should download? And if I make this app for BlackBerry 10, will it work for Playbook?

The purpose of doing it in WebWorks HTML5 is to target my BlackBerry app for both Playbook and BlackBerry 10 devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options, and its all about what you are targeting, or what your release horizon is:

### Release on the Playbook

If you want to release a Playbook application, Download [WebWorks SDK for BlackBerry PlayBook OS 2.2](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/#playbook) (Also called BlackBerry WebWorks SDK for Tablets). 
This will allow you to deploy to the following devices/services:

- A Development Playbook Device
- A Playbook Emulator (via VMware Player)
- Ripple Emulator
- App World

### Release for BB10 Devices

If you want to release software that targets BB10 devices download the [BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/#blackberry10) (currently in beta).

This will allow you to deploy to the following devices:

- Dev Alpha Handset
- Dev Alpha B handset
- BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha Simulator (via VMware player)
- Ripple emulator
- (Note you cannot deploy to App World yet for BB10 till ~2013)

### Release for both devices

Currently it isnt well known if a Webworks Application that targets playbook will run on BB10. The answer seems to be Yes (and No)  The [BBUI.js](https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js) project from RIM can be deployed to a Playbook Device and have the BB10 UI/UX. BBUI.js also targets the BB10 Webworks SDK, so as long as you are mindful of what APIs you use (nothing device specific...like NFC is only on BB10, etc), you will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Download HTML5/Webworks SDK for BlackBerry.

You can download it here: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/