# Can we make a universal blackberry app which runs on both blackberry 10 devices and playbook?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Develop an application for blackberry 10 and play book in webworks which sdk i should download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670636/develop-an-application-for-blackberry-10-and-play-book-in-webworks-which-sdk-i-s)

I want to make a blackberry app which can run both on blackberry devices and blackberry playbook. Can we write single code for some universal blackberry app which runs on both blackberry 10 devices and playbook?

Comment: Create an App using HTML 5. https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/

Comment: what sdk should i use?
Blackberry 10 or Blackberry Playbook?
I want to make a single app which could work for both!

Comment: you can chose any, up to your requirement.

Comment: " I want to make a single app which could work for both!" If I want to make a SINGLE APP which works for BOTH then?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue I don't think it is a dupe. The question you linked asks about webworks in particular, while this one doesn't say anything about webworks (only in the tags). It could be asking about C++ API as well.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking HTML5 applications...

When you package an HTML5 application with the WebWorks Tablet SDK, it actually converts that application to an AIR application; these will run on both the BlackBerry PlayBook and BlackBerry 10.

When you package an HTML5 application with the BB10 WebWorks SDK, the application remains an HTML5 application. BB10 packaged HTML5 applications will only run on the BB10 platform.

That being said, BlackBerry PlayBooks will be upgradeable to BlackBerry 10 in the future.

EDIT: As noted by others, you must be sure that you are only using APIs that are supported based on the SDK (Tablet or BB10) you are packaging with.